# HTML content locking?

Tags: html

A new client asked me to edit their web site.  The site was created with Xara Web Developer Premium.  I discover existing HTML code positioning EACH WORD of content on the page relative to the Left and Top margins!(?) Below:

Can you identify how this locking was created and how it can be repaired?

```
 <div class="xr_txt Normal_text Style11" style="position: absolute; left:296px; top:253px; width:611px; height:10px;font-family:'Georgia';font-feature-settings:'kern','liga' 0,'clig' 0,'calt' 0;">
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="top: -18.34px;font-family:'Georgia';"><span class="Normal_text Style11" style="font-family:'Georgia';font-weight:bold;">Beg’n &nbsp;</span></span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 63.51px; top: -18.34px;font-family:'Georgia';"><span class="Normal_text Style11" style="font-family:'Georgia';font-weight:bold;">Bark &nbsp;</span></span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 119.83px; top: -18.34px;font-family:'Georgia';"><span class="Normal_text Style11" style="font-family:'Georgia';font-weight:bold;">isnt &nbsp;</span></span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 165.12px; top: -18.34px;font-family:'Georgia';"><span class="Normal_text Style11" style="font-family:'Georgia';font-weight:bold;">just &nbsp;</span></span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 210px; top: -18.34px;font-family:'Georgia';"><span class="Normal_text Style11" style="font-family:'Georgia';font-weight:bold;">another &nbsp;</span></span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 298.03px; top: -18.34px;font-family:'Georgia';"><span class="Normal_text Style11" style="font-family:'Georgia';font-weight:bold;">pet &nbsp;</span></span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 336.79px; top: -18.34px;font-family:'Georgia';"><span class="Normal_text Style11" style="font-family:'Georgia';font-weight:bold;">sitting &nbsp;</span></span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 408.64px; top: -18.34px;font-family:'Georgia';"><span class="Normal_text Style11" style="font-family:'Georgia';font-weight:bold;">service. &nbsp;</span></span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 493.98px; top: -18.34px;font-family:'Georgia';">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 499.95px; top: -18.34px;font-family:'Georgia';">It's &nbsp;</span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 533.56px; top: -18.34px;font-family:'Georgia';">all &nbsp;</span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 561.05px; top: -18.34px;font-family:'Georgia';">about </span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="top: 4.38px;font-family:'Georgia';">how &nbsp;</span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 42.38px; top: 4.38px;font-family:'Georgia';">we &nbsp;</span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 72px; top: 4.38px;font-family:'Georgia';">love &nbsp;</span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 113.31px; top: 4.38px;font-family:'Georgia';">animals! &nbsp;</span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 194.96px; top: 4.38px;font-family:'Georgia';">Our &nbsp;</span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 234.75px; top: 4.38px;font-family:'Georgia';">entire &nbsp;</span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 292.07px; top: 4.38px;font-family:'Georgia';">staff &nbsp;</span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 335.91px; top: 4.38px;font-family:'Georgia';">treats &nbsp;</span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 391.51px; top: 4.38px;font-family:'Georgia';">each &nbsp;</span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 437.19px; top: 4.38px;font-family:'Georgia';">animal &nbsp;</span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 503.57px; top: 4.38px;font-family:'Georgia';">with &nbsp;</span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 547.93px; top: 4.38px;font-family:'Georgia';">respect </span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="top: 27.11px;font-family:'Georgia';">and &nbsp;</span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 40.6px; top: 27.11px;font-family:'Georgia';">care, &nbsp;</span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 90.24px; top: 27.11px;font-family:'Georgia';">in &nbsp;</span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 115.14px; top: 27.11px;font-family:'Georgia';">a &nbsp;</span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 132.45px; top: 27.11px;font-family:'Georgia';">professional &nbsp;</span>
 <span class="xr_tl Normal_text Style11" style="left: 247.79px; top: 27.11px;font-family:'Georgia';">manner. &nbsp;</span>
```

Comment: How is that "locking"? What do you mean "repaired"? What's your goal? Please revise to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Last time I had to deal with a site created with Xara, I threw the code away and rebuilt it from scratch. It's awful.

Comment: I suspect a non-programmer attempted to center a set of text. Simply strip all the junk markup and format it as you will. https://jsfiddle.net/vn0neycv/

Comment: isherwood - Your reply is most helpful.  Since posting, I have discovered this code was likely created by a design tool (in Xara line) not an HTML editor.  Since the ENTIRE site was created this way, any kind of modification is realistically impossible.  --  I appreciate your comment about my goal, a crucial omission.  When I posted I was thinking: "What IS going on here?".  Now I know.  Everything will have to be rebuilt.  Many Thanks!  ~:~ Jacob  --  (Will upvote, as soon as my upvote capability is enabled(?)).